# Who can identify this book about electronics

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt, books

The link to one of chapters is here:

https://ru.scribd.com/doc/38868597/Chapter-08-Bjt-Small-Signal-Analysis

Who is the author and what is the title?

Comment: Sedra & smith would be a random guess

Comment: https://archive.org/stream/ElectronicDevicesAndCircuitTheory11thEd.RobertL.Boylestad/Electronic%20Devices%20and%20Circuit%20Theory%2011th%20Ed.%2C%20Robert%20L.%20Boylestad#page/n37/mode/2up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electronic devices and circuit theory

Robert Boylestad & Louis Nashelsky, Prentice Hall